# Select ID and class at the same time in CSS in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css

I have a page as blow:

```
<ul class="ms-cui-tabBody ms-cui-tabBody-or" id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert-title" unselectable="on">
...
</ul>
```

I want to select ID and Class at the same time in CSS. But it doesn't work when I add CSS code to page.

```
#Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.ms-cui-tabBody{
height:78px!important;
background-color:green;}
```

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape periods in your IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12310128/1047998). So your code would be something like this.

```
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPInsert.ms-cui-tabBody 
{
    height:78px!important;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Hi,  the code works, but I have another id `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab` on the same page, your code works on this id. How can I only choose id `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert` ?

Comment: @MKQian: Ahh.. You wanted to select using both ID and class. I have updated my code to reflect that.